# Parallelize `apply_along_axis` within a Class method

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

#### Minimal Working Example

I have a class `MyClass` that is a abstract simplification of my actual problem. There's a method called `run_algorithm` that when it is called, it generates some `(100,10)` array named `z` and then at each iteration applies a method called `function` to the rows of `z`.

At the moment, this is done using `np.apply_along_axis(self.function, 1, z)`. However, I would like to parallelize this.

There are two levels of complexity:

1. At each iteration in `run_algorithm()` we change what the method `self.function` actually does (in this case, the difference is minimal since it is a MWE).
2. The function `self.function` is a method of the class and it keeps changing, meaning that I cannot use the standard multiprocessing stuff.

```py
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    
    def __init__(self, B=10, n_iterations=10):
        self.B = B 
        self.n_iterations = n_iterations
    
    def function1(self, z_row):
        """Takes numpy array z_row of dimension (d,) and returns
        numpy array of dimension (B+1, d)"""
        return np.arange(1, self.B+2).reshape(-1, 1) * z_row
    
    def function2(self, z_row):
        """Similar to function1 in terms of shapes, but does something slightly
        different."""
        return np.arange(1, (2*self.B)+2).reshape(-1, 1) * z_row
    
    def run_algorithm(self):
        """At each iteration chooses to apply either function1 or function2."""
        z = np.random.randn(100, 10)
        for i in range(self.n_iterations):
            print("Iteration: ", i)
            # Choose the function
            self.function = self.function1 if (i % 2 == 1) else self.function2
            # Apply the function using numpy (not in parallel)
            z_final = np.apply_along_axis(self.function, 1, z)
            # choose a random slice and start again
            index = np.random.choice(a=np.arange(self.B+1), size=1)[0]
            z = z_final[:, index, :]
        return z
```

#### What doesn't work

If `self.function` wasn't a method of a class, I could use `multiprocessing` by doing something like this:

```py
            def function_parallel(z):
                """Parallel version."""
                try:
                    with Pool(8) as p:
                        results = p.map(self.function, product(z))
                        return results
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    p.terminate()
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Exception occurred: ', e)
                    p.terminate()
                finally:
                    p.join()
            self.function_parallel = function_parallel
```

but this fails because multiprocessing needs a function defined in `main` but I can't have it since in my example the function depends on the state of the class itself.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a special function; it just iterates.  In your case with a 2d array, it's no better (and possibly slower) than `np.array([func(row) for row in arr])`.

Comment: Exactly my problem, I'd like to parallelize that!